# Calculate average, max and min based on water year

Tags: pandas

I can calculate the yearly averages, max and min values based on taking the first day of a year as January First like:

```
    yearly_avg=df2.groupby(years).mean()
    yearly_sum=df2.groupby(years).sum()
    yearly_MAX=df2.groupby(years).max()
    yearly_MIN=df2.groupby(years).min()
```

I need to calculate averages, max and min numbers based on the water year where October 1st is the first day of a year. As an explanation of "water year": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_year

Here is my sample file stored here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AYi9vp3_DPXHoCPB_YkMQp68FvC_INrV/view?usp=sharing

How can I do that?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you show a example of your dataframe?

Comment: Can you give us some example data to work with? Is "years" a timestamp column or just a year number? Also, can you clarify the question "where October first is the first day of the year" is a confusing condition as Oct. 1 is never the first day of any year.

Comment: I just edited my question and added sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the year to start on October instead of January. I am just happy your columns were already `datetime` types, this made it easier!

```py
df = pd.read_excel('sample_water_year.xlsx')
df['# YEAR'] = df.Dates.dt.to_period('A-Sep') #year ends on sep
```

Note that you will have to subtract 1 as it does not change the initial year value set.

```py
df['# YEAR'] = df['# YEAR'] - 1
```

Then simply find the summary statistics:

```py
yearly_avg = df.groupby('# YEAR').mean()
yearly_sum = df.groupby('# YEAR').sum()
yearly_MAX = df.groupby('# YEAR').max()
yearly_MIN = df.groupby('# YEAR').min()
```

Hopefully this helps!